# Voting to close as Off Topic and Belongs on Another SE Site Now Requires A Choice?

Tags: support, review, vote-to-close, migration

Sorry to add to what will surely be a stream of questions about the "on hold" stuff, but...

Previously, when I voted to put a question on hold as Off Topic, it presented me a list of other SE sites, but I didn't have to actually select one (in case the SE site that the question belonged on wasn't on that list).

Specifically, I would use this feature for questions that topically belong on CrossValidated, but that I don't really think should be migrated, due to quality issues. In those cases, it's nice to be tell the OP that their question is Off Topic, without dumping a bad question on another site.

But perusing the review queue it appears that the "Vote to Close" button is greyed out unless I actually select one of the specific SE sites shown to me.

Was this an actual feature change of the process, or is it just a hiccup?

Here's what I see:

[image]

Comment: You could use Off-Topic->Other and enter the address of the other site, but it would be very convenient to be able to select a site.

Comment: You shouldn't *need* to have an alternate site to refer to if a question is off topic. Often times there isn't one.

Comment: @MarkRansom However, when there is an appropriate site it would be nice to have the option. Even better defaults would be helpful. When was the last time we migrated TeX or Sharepoint questions on a regular basis?

Comment: @GeorgeCummins In my case, it most often comes up with questions that belong on CrossValidated. I will use "Other" for now, but it would be convenient to be able to save the extra typing and be able to just generally put on hold for a generic "belongs on another site" reason, with the site unspecified.

Comment: @GeorgeCummins That's a carefully chosen list, omitting the sites that _don't_ want SO's reject questions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You've gone too far.

Just select one of the options on the previous dialog:

[image: The off topic dialog]

If the question is simply off topic select one of the predefined reasons here or "Other" for a a custom message.

Only select the "This question belongs on an other site" option if it really does belong somewhere else, and then only if it belongs on one of the sites in the list. I admit it's not ideal that you have to select that further option to find the list.

I suppose another "Other" option on the second dialog might be useful. It would still cast a normal "off topic" vote (no migration) but it would allow us to capture where people think suitable off topic questions should migrated without people resorting to flags.

Comment: What if it belongs on a site that isn't on that list, but needs some editing by the OP before it's suitable for migration?

Comment: @joran - do one of the following: leave a comment, edit it yourself, choose the "other" option and explain for a moderator to review.

Comment: Ok. It's a little more work on my part, but them's the breaks, I suppose.

Comment: Using "Other" _leaves a comment on the question_.